# how do i get header chapter and specific page number latex?

Tags: header-footer

```
\newpage

\pagestyle{fancy}

\renewcommand{\chaptermark}[1]{\markboth{#1}{}}

\fancyhf{}%clearheaders

\fancyhead[R]{

\itshape

\leftmark}

\fancyfoot[C]{168}

\fancypagestyle{plain}{

\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0pt}

\fancyhf{}

\fancyfoot[C]{\168}
}

\setlength{\headheight}{14.5pt}

\setlength{\headheight}{14.5pt}
```

I want a header like this picture [image]

Comment: Have you looked into the package documentation?

Comment: I tried yes but with not the results i wanted

Comment: What document class are you using?  Book does this automatically (part of the \chapter definition), more or less.

Comment: What book?Sorry,but i am really new to latex

Comment: `\documentclass{book}` from file `book.cls`.

Comment: You should start by reading  an introduction.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be more specific to what class or packages you can/can't use, and please provide a [MWE](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-asked-to-write-a-minimal-example-what-is-that) next time.

If you use the `book` class you don't have to add any extra package for that effect.

[image]

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{book}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\begin{document}
\setcounter{page}{237}
\chapter{Introduction}\label{ch:intro}
\newpage

\lipsum[3]
\end{document}
```

If, however, for any reason you can't use book class or you must use a specific class. Then use `fancyhdr`:

[image]

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{report}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\pagestyle{headings}
\begin{document}
\setcounter{page}{237}
\chapter{Introduction}\label{ch:intro}
\newpage

\lipsum[3]
\end{document}
```